# CSS "Cover" - No scroll bars?

Tags: css

I am using the cover property to create a background image that fills the background and resizes with the browser. But I run into one issue, the page has a lot of content and no scroll bars appear for me to scroll down! Here is the code I am using:

```
body{ 
    background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /* Cover for IE 7/8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    /* End Cover for IE 7/8 */
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:2500px;
    max-height:1500px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

If I remove `position:fixed;` I get the scroll bars back but the background image disappears. What is the best way to tackle this and have both scroll bars and the background cover image?

Note: I am using jQuery and would use a JS answer if it works (though I prefer a CSS only answer.)

***UPDATE***

I removed `fixed` from the:

> background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

and that shows the scroll bars again but when I scroll the image gets covered by a black background as I scroll. I would prefer the image stay fixed and show scroll bars.

[Here is a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/3BTSx/1/)

Comment: Remove fixed from your background rule.

Comment: @j08691 - Read what I said below the code, removing `position:fixed;` removed the background image

Comment: I didn't say remove `position:fixed`, I said remove fixed from your background rule. Also, it would be helpful if you showed the rest of your code and/or a jsFiddle. BTW why does your body have a z-index?

Comment: @j08691 - My apologies, I misread. I will work on a fiddle, as for the z-index, I original had tried this as a div that wrapped the entire page but changed it to the body and the z-index was left over and I forgot to remove it. (The div had the same issue as above.)

Comment: @j08691 - [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/3BTSx/1/) - You will see a black bar come over the image. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my method of background image and used the method found [here](http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code).

Here is the Code:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#full-screen-background-image {
 z-index: -999;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1024px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 800px;
 min-height: 400px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 color: #333;
}

<body>
  <img alt="full screen background image" src="/background.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
      <p>Content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I found my background was showing over the image so I added this class to the body:

```
.transparent{
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

One other issue that arose was my background was black, with a transparent background-color white shows before the image is loaded. To get around this issue I created a loading div and had the page load then add the class to the body.

***Code:***

*HTML*

```
<body>
   <div id="loading">
  <h2 class="textcenter">Loading...</h2>
  <img id="loading-image" class="center" src="ajax-loader.gif" />
</div> 
 <div style="display:none;" id="content-wrap">
  <img alt="full screen background image" src="/background.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
      <p>Content goes here...</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

*JS*

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow", function() {
      $("body").addClass("transparent");
   });    
 });   
});
```

We end with a solution that I tested IE 8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and actually works! =>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your page, the body may not get resized to 100% width/height depending on the rest of the HTML/CSS. Do you have floated/absolutely positioned elements?

You can try removing the `position:fixed` as well as the `top`, `bottom`, `height` and `width` attributes, and adding this above the CSS you gave:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 2500px;
    max-height: 1500px;
}
```

It would be helpful to see snippets of your layout HTML/CSS as that may be affecting the body.

Answer (score 0):

try append styles to html, not to body...

```
html{ 
    background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: if add in html means background image not display, plz verify

Answer (score 0):

just put **100% instead of cover** in background size add **height:100% in overlay** then background image should comes in any size content.

```
body{ 
    background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    /* Cover for IE 7/8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    /* End Cover for IE 7/8 */
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:2500px;
    max-height:1500px;
    z-index:1;
} 
.overlay{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /*Fallback */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position:relative;height:100%;
}
```